# What exactly constitutes a "hot" question anyway?

Tags: discussion, meta

I ask this because it never fails to amaze me which questions get featured in the hot questions from the network side bar.

The first obvious one is, uh, the one from which I got like thirty percent of my rep (hey, I'm not complaining): [What does ø mean after a chord?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/45311/what-does-%C3%B8-mean-after-a-chord/45312#45312)

And, you know, fine, that's a fair question. I might feel like maybe there are plenty more interesting questions that might deserve more attention.

Today, and this one is inexplicable to me -- [How much interpretation is up to the performer?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/49848/how-much-interpretation-is-up-to-the-performer)

Fine! Great question! I mean, I suppose it's a *little* bit *way* too broad, but it's interesting.

The question is because It only has one upvote, and two answers, and like four comments... Basically, I can think of a bajillion other questions that have generated more attention quicker.

And yet, I just saw it pop up in the side bar.

Just curious... What exactly is the algorithm for selecting "hot" questions?

Comment: This is covered numerous times on meta.SE. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/154443

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SE as a whole, not music.SE